# How to make custom slide change button in Swiper? (Vue.js)

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

I need to delete default navigation (nextEl, prevEl) and make button with "NEXT SLIDE BUTTON" text scroll to next slide

```
<swiper class="news-slider" :sliderd-per-view="1" :modules="[Navigation, Pagination, A11y, Lazy]" navigation="navigation" :navigation="{ nextEl: '.nextArrow'}" :pagination="{ clickable: true, dynamicBullets: true, dynamicMainBullets: 5 }" preload-images="false" lazy="lazy"> 
  <swiperSlide class="swiper-slide" v-for="n in 10" :key="n">
    <div class="news-container"> 
      <div class="news"><img class="news__image swiper-lazy" src="@/assets/img/lookism-transformed-transformed.png" alt=""/>
        <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
        <div class="news__info">
          <div class="news__title">title</div>
          <div class="news__description">description</div>
          <div class="news__buttons">
            <button class="normal-button news-button">more</button>
            <button class="next-button"><span class="next-button__text">NEXT SLIDE BUTTON</span><img class="next-button__icon" src="@/assets/img/arrow-right.svg" alt=""/></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </swiperSlide>
</swiper>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {
      Swiper,
      SwiperSlide,
    },
    setup() {
      const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
        console.log(swiper);
        
      };
      const onSlideChange = () => {
        console.log('slide change');
      };
      return {
        onSwiper,
        onSlideChange,
        modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y],
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

How can i do that? I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: Example of custom next/prev: https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/jOWjWMM?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

`useSwiper` & `swiper.slideNext()` leads to nowhere.

In our HTML section we need to first assign a ref to our `swiper` element, for example `ref="swiperRef"`.
We also need to import Navigation module like `:modules="[Navigation]"`, So our HTML Section should look like this:

```
<template>
    <swiper
        ref="swiperRef"
        :slides-per-view="1"
        @swiper="onSwiper"
        :loop="true"
        :modules="[Navigation]"
    >
        <swiper-slide>
            <div class="slide slide-1"></div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide>
            <div class="slide slide-2"></div>
        </swiper-slide>
        <swiper-slide>
            <div class="slide slide-3"></div>
        </swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
</template>
```

And This is what we need in our script section:

```
<script>
import {defineComponent, ref} from 'vue';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/css';

import { Navigation  } from 'swiper/modules';


export default defineComponent({
    methods: {
        Navigation() {
            return Navigation
        }
    },
    components: {
        Swiper,
        SwiperSlide,
    },
    setup() {

        const swiperInstance = ref()

        function onSwiper(swiper) {
            swiperInstance.value = swiper
        }
        const swiperNextSlide = () => {
            swiperInstance.value.slideNext()
        };
        const swiperPrevSlide = () => {
            swiperInstance.value.slidePrev()
        };
        return {
            swiperPrevSlide,
            swiperNextSlide,
            onSwiper,
        };
    },
});
</script>
```

And now we have 2 methods that we can use in a button onclick:

```
<button type="button" @click="swiperPrevSlide"> Prev Slide </button>
<button type="button" @click="swiperNextSlide"> Prev Slide </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, all you need to do is import `useSwiper` and assign it to a const variable and use it in the div element as `swiper.slideNext()`

And also if you do not wish to use swiper's own elements then remove the `navigation` module.

Here's the doc source which is clearer

https://swiperjs.com/vue#use-swiper

Comment: fyi: this only works if your button element is inside of the swiper container